# Key column doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I'm having trouble adding a foreign key field that references another table.

First I created the users table as so:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
user_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
userName VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
userEmail VARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
userPwd VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
);
```

then I'd like the quizzes table to have a foreign key that references the user_id from the first table

```
CREATE TABLE quizzes (
quizId INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
quizName VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
quizMax SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);
```

This is throwing the error: 'Key column 'user_id' doesn't exist in table.

Other answers advised to check that DB is InnoDB, which I did, and it is.

Can't understand why it's telling me that user_id doesn't exist, when it clearly does exist in the users table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly check if table `user` is created successfully, due to the additional ',' on last column!

Secondly, the column you reffered in `FOREIGN KEY(user_id)` is not defined in table `quizzes`, you need to add this column in `quizzes` table.

Comment: Thank you, it now works. I didn't realise that you needed to create the column before declaring it as a foreign key. Thought it did it automatically :) Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

- First: You do not need the last comma - `,` in the first CREATE statement. -
- Second: you have to create the columns before you can use them in a foreign key constraint and user_id does not exist in the second table at the moment of constraint creation.

Take a look at the example below. The last create succeeds when user_id column is added before the constraint is created:

[image]

Comment: No worries, it happens to the best of us ;)