# Not able to drop field in MariaDB table

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I have table `my_transitions` and I am trying to delete field called `myStage`.

I am using this command:

```
alter table `my_transitions` drop `myStage`
```

I am seeing this error:

`Key column 'myStage' doesn't exist in table`

But when I list all fields using this command:
`describe my_transitions`

I can see

```
id  bigint(20) unsigned NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
myStage varchar(255)    NO  MUL NULL    
updated_at  timestamp   YES     NULL
```

Anyone can see if I am doing something wrong?

EDIT:

If I run `show create table my_transitions;`, I am getting:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_transitions` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `myStage` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `myStage1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_stage_combination` (`myStage`,`myStage1`),
  KEY `my_transitions_myStage` (`myStage`),
  KEY `my_transitions_myStage1` (`myStage1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Key column doesn't exist in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040509/key-column-doesnt-exist-in-table)

Comment: No it doesn't. I do have that field in the table :/

Comment: That error is common when trying to define a foreign key incorrectly, but not when trying to drop a column. I believe the error is coming from another statement, not your alter table that drops the column.

Comment: I did a test directly of the above alter table query directly in the db and it is coming from there

Comment: can you please post the result from **show create table my_transitions;**

Comment: @BerndBuffen Done. I edited the question.

Comment: i have tested and anything look good. which version you using. i have found this problem in mariadb 10.2.8 see: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13613 when the field is a part of a key

Comment: Are you using MariaDB? What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Comment: Hm, I have this version 10.5.8-MariaDB

Comment: can you drop the key my_transitions_myStage  first and test again

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by first deleting the unique key
`ALTER TABLE my_transitions DROP INDEX unique_stage_combination;`

It seems like it is not possible to delete a column if it is a part of index key in Maria DB 10.5.8.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pecular bug in MariaDB. It affects MariaDB 10.5.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=867204670347fa29e40bd5eb510c6956

The workaround is to drop the UNIQUE KEY that column `mystage` is part of first, then drop the column.

```
alter table my_transitions drop key unique_stage_combination, drop column mystage;
```

P.S.: I tested this on MySQL 8.0 and it does not require the workaround. It does drop the column, but it leaves the table with a UNIQUE KEY column on just one column `mystage1`, which might not be what you want.

Comment: Unsuccessfully Tested your workaround when a foreign key exists https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68286706/not-able-to-drop-field-in-mariadb-table-with-foreign-key