# Not able to drop field in MariaDB/MySql table with FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I tried to apply the workaround described in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66946796/not-able-to-drop-field-in-mariadb-table) with no success.

In my scenario there are two related tables; I wish to drop the `ean_code` field from table `product`.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `brand` (
>   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `name` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `product` (
>   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   `ean_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `brand_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>   UNIQUE KEY `product_eancode_unique` (`brand_id`,`ean_code`),
>   CONSTRAINT `fk_product_brand_id` FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`) REFERENCES `brand` (`id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
> ```

As explained by @bill-karwin the plain `drop column` fails:

```sql
> ALTER TABLE product drop column `ean_code`;
  Key column 'ean_code' doesn't exist in table
```

So I tried the suggested workaround "drop both the unique index and the field in the same statement":

```sql
> ALTER TABLE `product` DROP KEY `product_eancode_unique`, DROP COLUMN  `ean_code`;
  Cannot drop index 'product_eancode_unique': needed in a foreign key constraint
```

The error reported is quite peculiar in my opinion since the given field is NOT involved in any relation between the two tables;

I experimented the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=7ce1d7374a9b46aaa38aff3d7c53c427) with all available mariadb and mysql versions with no joy.

PS I've isolated the culprit constraint by trial and error using db-fiddle but ant db instance will do the job (apart from experimenting with different db versions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot drop the column because the foreign key constraint uses this index. You must create an index which will be used for constraint checking firstly and drop index which includes the column to be dropped. Then the column may be dropped.

```sql
ALTER TABLE product ADD INDEX (brand_id), 
                    DROP INDEX product_eancode_unique,  
                    DROP COLUMN `ean_code`;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=f36688300eeff3af867872b0227981ac

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I've found myself is "drop the constraint before dropping index and field, then recreate the constraint".

```sql
alter table `product` drop constraint `fk_product_brand_id`;
alter table `product` drop key `product_eancode_unique`, drop column `ean_code`;
alter table `product` add foreign key `fk_product_brand_id`(`brand_id`) REFERENCES `brand`(`id`)
```

As in this [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=2e1856657708ba0b485875a7f1ceb7fa).

Still I do not know how to quickly isolate the constraint causing all this.

Comment: Accepted @akina 's answer, my workaround leaves you without a useful index.